# Redux: the previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I add middleware for chrome extension, reducers stop working properly on site (but chrome/redux debug tool works) + I get following error in console:

> The previous state received by the reducer has unexpected type of "Function". Expected argument to be an object with the following keys: "auth", "common", "home"

Here is code:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware } from './middleware';
import reducer from './reducer';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware);

const store = createStore(reducer, middleware,
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f);

export default store;
```

If I remove chrome part:

```
,window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
```

If works normal again.

Comment: As the error says, you need to look in the reducer, so it would be helpful if you provided your reducer code.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`createStore` takes up to 3 arguments. If the second argument is a function it assumes that your second argument is the store enhancer. If it is an object or *there are 3 arguments present* it assumes that the argument is your **initial state**. See [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md).

Your middleware variable is a store enhancer and the chrome extension is also an enhancer:

```
window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
```

You have to compose both in a single function:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware } from './middleware';
import reducer from './reducer';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, localStorageMiddleware);

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  compose(middleware, window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
);

export default store;
```

Documentation for this can be found [here](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#2-use-with-redux).

Answer (score 18):

`createStore` [accepts the following arguments](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md):

- reducer
- preloaded state
- enhancer

If only two arguments supplied and the second argument is a function, then it's considered to be an enhancer. See more in the [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js).

If you want to use Redux devtools, then you should `compose` it as an additional enhancer.

```
    import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';

    const store = createStore(
      reducer,
      compose(
        middleware,
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
      )
    )
```

Hope that helps. Pozdrav